# Turn on/off my own log(cout) prints in c++ - how to do that? any special option?

Tags: c++, debugging, logging, cout

I use cout and printf for my debugging. However, when i want to run a "clean" code without cout messages

i have to comment out every single one. How can i turn on/off

example:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){

    cout << "=======================" <<endl ;

    for(int j = 0 ; j < 5 ; j++){
              cout << j " "  ;

              int sum = i + j ; //actual work

            }
    }
```

can i compile it somehow with a some option? like this: g++ main.cpp -no_log
and it does not print any couts? How do developers do it in c++?

Answer (score 4):

Guard it with a debug macro:

```
#ifdef DEBUG_MODE
   cout << "whatever";
#endif
```

Or wrap it in a class so you don't have to write the macro every time:

```
class Log
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    Log& operator << (const T& x)
    {
    #ifdef DEBUG_MODE
        std::cout << x;
    #endif
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a macro such as

```
#define COUT if (0) cout
```

and replace every occurrence of `cout`.

You can enable the logs by changing the 0 to a 1. If you substitute the 0 with the name of a global Boolean variable, you can even make this setting dynamic (run-time).

Answer (score 1):

For a serious application one will set up a logging framework (logger can have different logging levels and you only output something if the level of a message is greater or equal than the level of your logger).

For an example of a logging framework see: [Poco Logging Framework](http://pocoproject.org/slides/110-Logging.pdf)

For a quick solution:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
cout << "debug message" << endl;
#endif
```

Notice that you will have to define `DEBUG` if in debugging build e.g by passing `-D Debug` to the compiler command line options.

VC already comes with `_DEBUG` defined (`Defined when you compile with /LDd, /MDd, and /MTd.`). See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx

Answer (score 0):

---

I would recommend using Boost logging:

> The core also provides another way to disable logging. By calling the
>   set_logging_enabled with a boolean argument one may completely disable
>   or reenable logging, including applying filtering. Disabling logging
>   with this method may be more benefical in terms of application
>   performance than setting a global filter that always fails.

http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed.html